# Worklight 6.1 :How to clear session on worklight server at adapter level

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am handling session on server side and i am able to manage that by using adapter side code

```
var cookie = WL.Server.getClientRequest().getHeader('Cookie');
    var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest();
    var session = request.getSession();
    var sessionid = session.getId();
```

But the problem is every time i am hitting the adapter i am getting the same session on server side.
How to kill that session on adapter side so that i can create new session every time i hit the adapter.

I tried session.invalidate() but no use for me. After doing this also i am getting the same session on server side.

Please suggest what need to be done on server side or adapter side.

Answer (score 0):

It will help greatly if you will explain exactly what you want to achieve. As it is, you are not explaining it clearly enough.

---

If you're talking about the server between the Worklight Server and the backend, then:

To get a new session with every adapter request sent to the backend, you need to set the `connectAs` property to `endUser` on the relevant procedure:

> ```
> <procedure name="getStories" connectAs="endUser"/>
> ```

Refer to the following blog post which explains it at length: 
[Configuring HTTP adapters for stateless/stateful backend connectivity and user identity propagation](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/configuring_http_adapters_for_stateless_stateful_backend_connectivity_and_user_identity_propagation?lang=en)

---

If you're actually talking about the session creating when invoking the adapter on the client-side, then you cannot invalidate the session on the adapter-level. The only way to get a new session would be to re-open the application (assuming the session has already expired between the client and the Worklight Server, you'll then get a new session).

Comment: I don't want new session for every adapter request. I just want new session at first call to any adapter then it should be same throughout the app..

Comment: What do you mean "first time" you call the adapter? You need to better explain what you are trying to do. You specifically wrote: "i am hitting the adapter i am getting the same session on server side. How to kill that session on adapter side **so that i can create new session every time i hit the adapter**".

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a default WL server behaviour. You'll get a new session created first time you hit the server and this session will be reused till it times out.

Comment: So if in my app i have given the functionality for logout then how will i kill the session which is active and get a new session for the same.